# Jquery UI draggable and droppable with option of resizing and sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code on Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinprasad/753KX/1/.

Here is my jquery code:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert : true
        });
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            connectToSortable : "#sortable",
            helper : "clone",
            revert: function(valid) {
                if(valid) {
                    //alert("Valid");
                    $("ul#sortable li").resizable();
                    $("#sortable").sortable({revert : true  });
                    $("ul, li").disableSelection();
                }
                return !valid;
            }
        });
        $("ul, li").disableSelection();

        $("ul#sortable li").resizable({

        });
    /*   $( "#sortable li" ).droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                return false;
                }
        }); */

    });
```

The droppable doesn't seem to be working as even if I'm comment the droppable, its functionalities remains same.

What I have to do is:

1. Make item1,item2 .... as drop containers where facebook or twitter items can be dropped but only one at a time.Eg If twitter is dropped it should not allow any other items to be dropped and even twitter.
2. Make the dropped items sortable and users can also resize the items.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.